# How to retrieve records from two times using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, functional-testing, database-testing

I have a table named callinfo and it has records like below.

```
call#         callstarted                  callended

 1        03-04-2013 12:04:28 pm       03-04-2013  01:37:07 pm
 2        03-04-2013 01:15:02 pm       03-04-2013  02:12:15 pm
 3        04-05-2013 11:45:01 am       04-05-2013  01:20:35 pm
```

How can i retrieve records from callinfo between 1:00 pm to 1:15 pm?

Comment: Do you want to add date (e.g. 03-04-2013) also or just this timestamp you want to have in condition?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are date columns:

```
select * 
from callinfo
where  callstarted>=to_date(to_char(callstarted,'DD-MON-YYYY')||' 13:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
and    callended<=to_date(to_char(callended,'DD-MON-YYYY')||' 13:15','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
```